# SSL/HTTPS and XCart - installation/setup

Tags: ssl, https, x-cart

I have:

1. Installed XCart (Gold Plus 4.6.0 - Trial with Lexity Live) on Netfirms
2. Purchased (and successfully installed) a RapidSSL Premium Certificate from GeoTrust through Netfirms
3. Enabled SSL in XCart and updated config file appropriately.

When I run Settings::Security Settings I receive error under HTTPS Options, "Warning! HTTPS/SSL check failed. Please make sure that HTTPS is configured properly."

Question: If the certificate is installed and the software knows to go to the secure server address what could be the problem?

I realize more background info is necessary. Please help. I know nothing of ssl. I read somewhere quickly in the past year or so something about symlink-ing, etc. I don't believe this to be of use here. Perhaps I am incorrect.

All my love,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you have SSL configured in your browser, it should just work.  Make sure your cert is actually installed correctly.

You can test it with the [SSL Installation Diagnostics Tool](http://www.digicert.com/help/).

If that actually comes back ok for your site, then your best bet will be to check the syslog, perhaps something is not configured properly in your webserver config?

Comment: The best thing I can say (given my lack of SSL knowledge is) Netfirms can be difficult to work with some times. SSL GeoTrust Certificates included.... thanks for the direction.